# How to unlock the final game with each girl?

Tags: huniepop

In the game HuniePop, how do you unlock the final games for each girl? Is there something specific required to access these sections? I keep giving them presents and playing that block-matching game they always want you to play, but I'm no further on.

How do I get to the final stage with each girl in HuniePop?

Comment: [Your joke was fun](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29971165#29971165), but [we hate fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) (and it wasn't much child friendly either (nor is the game, but whatever)).

Comment: @ardaozkal I have the censored Steam version. It's pretty tame. I mostly like the voice acting. I'm not even really kidding.

Comment: Are you telling me that it has an uncensored version?

Comment: @ardaozkal It does, but not through Steam.

Comment: @ardaozkal The Humble Bundle and MangaGamer versions are uncensored. And there's a patch for the Steam version.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I like to play the games with the art the artist originally created.

Comment: @ardaozkal don't we all?...

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter-Poulsen I know you can match more than 3 blocks but the genre as a whole is generally referred to as match-3 because that's the lowest number you can match.

Comment: @AshleyNunn Why would anyone ask a girl to put a shoe 0n her head? I mean, really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go on 4 successful dates with a girl. The 4th one needs to be a night date. Once you're successful at 4 dates, you will have to play one more round of the match-3 game ([with slightly different rules](http://huniepop.wikia.com/wiki/Date)):

"The affection level is lower than the average date affection level, but the score decays over time, so players must play the bonus stage as fast as possible in order to win.

Every token grants 10 pleasure, including passion and sentiment tokens, so players do not need to worry about that girls' preferred traits when playing."

Once you've done that, you will unlock the final reward for that character.

Comment: Ah yes, it was the night-date that was the thing. Always with the night dates.